# Spotify Play Button is not working - playing only previews in recent Chrome

Tags: api, google-chrome, iframe, embed, spotify

I was going back and forth with Spotify Cares Twitter for over four days. Finally they directed me here, so I hope one of the devs from Spotify will answer.

I am trying to put Spotify Play Button on the website. I was following the [instructions from the documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/widgets/generate/play-button/). Then I also [found on the Spotify blog](https://developer.spotify.com/community/news/2018/07/19/new-updates-to-spotify-play-button/), that some details had changed in July 2018. So I have tried this code as well.

Whatever I did, the Play Button embed player plays only preview (30 seconds) when accessing website in the Chrome (version 68 and 69).

The code is simple and straight taken from the documentation/blog:

```
<iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed?uri=spotify:album:1DFixLWuPkv3KT3TnV35m3" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

This code I have put into the empty HTML, so completely no other code interfering. You can check it [in the example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/ivellios/pen/LJdWgm).

I have tried to isolate the issue and here's what I have found:

- In Chrome it never works: neither when I am logged into Spotify nor when I am not and log in with the button that shows up in the player
- In Chrome with/without SSL - in both cases it didn't work
- In Firefox it works properly. When I log into Spotify on the browser, go to the page, it plays full tracks
- Also asked my friends to go to the page with this code and - being logged into Spotify - it didn't work for them as well
- The play button works properly in the examples on blog and documentation of Spotify - which is in their domain, so it is the same domain as the iframe content - this is a hint I think.
- I have checked also recent changes in Chrome, but only one concerning iframe was adding `allow` on microphone and camera. Even using this one didn't help (but this should not be related actually).
- I have also checked on recent Safari / MacOS - the issue is there as well (but not on Firefox/MacOS)

What can be the reason for the issue? How to solve this? Or maybe Spotify devs team need to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer is quite obvious if you know where to look.

Under `chrome://settings/content/cookies` Google Chrome has this option *Block third-party cookies*. I had it enabled and that was the cause of the issue.

But why I didn't think of it before? It's because Google Chrome in such case adds to all non-white-listed (see below) sites a cookie icon with red *X* to the right side of the Address Bar. When one clicks it, it shows two options:

- *Always allow [url of the site] site to save cookies*
- *Keep blocking the cookies*

And since I had the first one selected it looked good to me back then.

But this option is not the same as "allow use of the third-party cookies", which is not available in the popup options window.

**In fact to allow sites to use cookies from Spotify, you have to either:**

1. Disable the option *Block third-party cookies* in the Chrome Settings in general
2. or add `[*.]spotify.com` to your white-list (I recommend this one)

And that way, any site can access `spotify.com` cookies to check if user is logged in to properly play music (full tracks or just previews).

**And one final note:** the site with the embed play button code must be accessed with SSL, so via `https`.

I didn't check how to change that for Safari on MacOS, but probably the solution is similar to this one.